# What does (value << 32) >> 32 mean?

Tags: c++

I am facing with the code where for me there is a extraordinary operations like this:

```
return std::pair<T1, T2>(value >> 32, ( (value << 32) >> 32) );
```

What does this mean: `( (value << 32) >> 32)` .

Is this the same as just `value` ? (for me it is reasonable when the size of value type is 64 bit)

Comment: wow, using bitwise operations with templates types ?! depending on the types (short, uint, double) it can have several outputs.

Comment: there is a missing parenthesis moreover.

Comment: This may be dangerous. It's undefined to shift an integer by its number of bits. If they are 32-bit values, the result is undefined.

Comment: It means that whoever wrote the code didn't understand bit masks, so wrote a bad hack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this the same as just `value`?

No.

since zero's are shifted in (value << 32) >> 32) discards the top 32 bits.

`(value << 32) >> 32)` is the bottom 32 bits

`value >> 32` is the top 32 bits

[That's assuming you start with a 64 bit type. If you have a 32 bit type, then it's undefined behaviour]

Comment: And assuming that `operator>>` has not been overwritten for the type of `value`, of course.

Comment: It's undefined to shift an integer by its number of bits. If they are 32-bit values, the result is undefined.

Comment: If you have a 32-bit type then it's undefined behaviour (pet peeve of mine actually).

Comment: With C++11, `value << 32` is well defined for 32-bit types; its value is 0.

Comment: Whether zeros are shifted in with `>>` depends on the type and the implimentation.  And what if you have a  48 bit type?

Comment: Assuming you start with a 64-bit **unsigned** type.

Answer (score 5):

The code may aiming at split the an unsigned 64-bit integer ( uint64_t ) to 2 parts:

The low components ( bits 0 .. 31 )

And the high components ( bits 32 .. 63 )

val >> 32, will get the high components of v.

and (val << 32) >> 32 will get the low components of v.

`val: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`

`val >> 32: 00000000000000000000000000000000 xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

`val << 32: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy 00000000000000000000000000000000`

`(val<<32)>>32: 0000000000000000000000000000000 yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy`

**Notice: if val if a signed integer, you may not get the answer as expected.**

Answer (score 4):

When `value`'s type is a 64bit integer, then `(value << 32) >> 32)` will return the "rightmost" 32 Bits of it!

`return std::pair<T1, T2>(value >> 32, (value << 32) >> 32) );` actually splits a 64 Bit integer into its two 32 Bit parts ;)

Answer (score 3):

It looks like this code is attempting to split a 64-bit number into a high 32-bit word and a low 32-bit word.

If we *assume* that `value` is an *unsigned* 64-bit integer then:

```
value >> 32
```

is the most significant 32-bit word (the bottom 32-bits spill off the end as the high word is shifted into the low word position). And:

```
(value << 32) >> 32
```

is the least significant 32-bit word rammed up into the high portion (bumping off the existing high portion) and then moved back down into the lower 32-bit section. This could also be achieved by stating:

```
value & 0xFFFFFFFF
```

Answer (score 3):

`<<` and `>>` are bitwise operands.

They shift the bits of the number to the right `>>` or to the left `<<`.

For a 64 bit integer:

```
value >> 32 = top 32 bits.
(value << 32) >> 32 = bottom 32 bits.
```

Answer (score 2):

If your value is, as you say, 64bits long, this expression will cut `value` in order to fill the 'leftmost' 32bits with 0 :

Suppose `value` is :
    0xA3B252A2ADAEACA0

Then `value << 32` is :
    0xADAEACA000000000

And `(value << 32) >> 32` is :
    0x00000000ADAEACA0

The first part of you `std::pair` is `value << 32` and it will do the opposite of that, returning only the 'leftmost' half of `value` :
    0x00000000A3B252A2

Your instruction line will cut your 64bits into two 32bits consecutive values.